# Как сделать сохранение всего выбранного на сайте в Cookie пользователя?

Tags: javascript, cookie

Имеется сайт, где от нажатия на кнопки происходит смена картинок. Как сохранить выбранную пользователем картинку?

Comment: смена картинок - понятие растяжимое. что у вас? слайдер, смена бекграунда? или еще что-то?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос сформулирован неясно... Сохранить на компьютере? Для этого нужно почитать про технологию Blob. Если у вас слайдер и нужно сохранять позицию картинки после перезагрузки страницы, используйте localStorage.